# macOS Big Sur toolbar item width with image

Tags: macos, appkit, nstoolbaritem

I'm trying to create an `NSToolbar` with items similar to the Apple's Mail app on macOS. I have an issue with the default toolbar item's width though, as it seems to be inconsistent. Since Big Sur, the items are meant to be sized automatically by AppKit and the `NSToolbarItem` `minSize`, `maxSize` properties have been deprecated.

I'm setting the `image` property for each `NSToolbarItem`, not using custom views. As you can see in the screenshots below, the envelope icon has a different "highlight" area (less padding on the sides) while the trash icon has a much larger highlight area.

[image: Single item]

[image: Group items]

The envelope icon is a single `NSToolbarItem` while the archive box and trash items are displayed using `NSToolbarItemGroup` with `NSSegmentedControl` view.

In the Apple's Mail app, even single toolbar items have the same width as the grouped items:

[image: Apple Mail toolbar]

How to increase the toolbar item's width when using an image instead of custom view?

Answer (score 1):

Deprecating a property and leaving you in the dark how to achieve a until recently simple effect without using the deprecated property is typical for how Apple deals with AppKit nowadays.

I would not be surprised of the Mail app still uses the deprecated `minSize`  property, or that the `NSToolbarItem` objects are based on `NSButton` views with a minimum width `NSLayoutConstraint` (which is my current solution).

To continue using `minSize` without deprecation warnings, you can consider to use a simple `ToolbarItem` class like this:

```
class ToolbarItem: NSToolbarItem {
    override var minSize: NSSize {
        get {
            return NSSize(width: 50, height: 30)
        }
        set {}
    }
}
```